# Animate circles using HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does any one know how to make the following animation with the text and clock in html and CSS as seen in the link below?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/pewcewot8b61tsl/20210629_165919_edited.mp4?dl=0

The issue with my code is that the live clock and the circle keeps on moving out of place when I resize my window, or when I use responsive mode.

So far I've got this:

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
    
  background-color:rgb(62,180,137) ;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;

}
.col-sm-2 > span, .col-sm-2 > p {
  display: inline-block;
    
}
[class*="col-"] {
   /*This will make all the elements using the class "col-" float left, have a width of 100%, box sizing, border, it will hide the overflow and add a padding of 16px */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 220px;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {left: 0px;}
  50% {left: 190px;}
  100%{left :0px;}
}
.dot2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
    
  background-color:rgb(62,180,137) ;
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {left: 0px;}
  50% {left: 190px;}
  100%{left :0px;}
}

.text{
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: "Nunito";
    font-weight: bolder;
    display: inline-block;
}
.clock {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 42%;
    color: black;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: center">
     <span><div class="dot"></div><div class="dot2"></div></span><p class="text">metal</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="DigitalCLOCK" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
  <script  src="function.js"></script>
        <br>
        <script>
            
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
// Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com )
function showTime(){
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours(); 
    var m = date.getMinutes(); 
    var s = date.getSeconds(); 
    
    
    if(h == 0){
        h = 12;
    }
    
    if(h > 24){
        h = h - 12;
        
    }
    
    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;
    
    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " ";
    document.getElementById("DigitalCLOCK").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("DigitalCLOCK").textContent = time;
    
    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);
    
}
 
showTime();
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`#DigitalCLOCK` is absolutely positioned. To maintain its position on resize, apply `position:relative` to its wrapper.

```css
.dot {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(62, 180, 137);
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  position:absolute;
  animation-delay: 1.8s;
  bottom:90px;
}

.col-sm-2>span,
.col-sm-2>p {
  display: inline-block;
}

[class*="col-"] {
  /*This will make all the elements using the class "col-" float left, have a width of 100%, box sizing, border, it will hide the overflow and add a padding of 16px */
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 220px;
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  25%{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 190px;
     height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  }
  75%{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

.dot2 {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgb(62, 180, 137);
  position: relative;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}


.text {
  font-size: 70px;
  font-family: "Nunito";
  font-weight: bolder;
  display: inline-block;
}

.clock {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 28%;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2" style="text-align: center;position:relative">
    <span><div class="dot"></div><div class="dot2"></div></span>
    <p class="text">metal</p>
    <div id="DigitalCLOCK" class="clock" onload="showTime()"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="function.js"></script>
<br>
<script>
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9
  10
  11
  12
  13
  14
  15
  16
  17
  18
  19
  20
  21
  22
  23
  24
  25
  26
  27
  28
  29
  30
  // Code By Webdevtrick ( https://webdevtrick.com )
  function showTime() {
    var date = new Date();
    var h = date.getHours();
    var m = date.getMinutes();
    var s = date.getSeconds();


    if (h == 0) {
      h = 12;
    }

    if (h > 24) {
      h = h - 12;

    }

    h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
    m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
    s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

    var time = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " ";
    document.getElementById("DigitalCLOCK").innerText = time;
    document.getElementById("DigitalCLOCK").textContent = time;

    setTimeout(showTime, 1000);

  }

  showTime();
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that's fixed do you know how to make the circle fix in one position as they move aswell, I've tried position relative and absolute but nothing, and also do you know to animate the circles as seen in the video?

Comment: @ZainQalandar What do you mean? The circles are animated properly and their position are in one position.

Comment: when I change window size or go to responsive mode you will see the circles will move up, also yes the animation is pretty similar but I wanted to add that fade effect as seen here https://www.dropbox.com/s/pewcewot8b61tsl/20210629_165919_edited.mp4?dl=0

Comment: @ZainQalandar Have you tried running the snippet? When I resize the window the circles don't move. Also, I don't see a fade effect in the example.

Comment: yes I've tried the snippet when I go into responsive mode then the circles move up and in the video you can see that the circle size increases and decreases

Comment: @ZainQalandar try it now. It should work.

Comment: still having the same issue, now the word metal is also moving, I've recorder the screen to make it easier here is the link. https://www.dropbox.com/s/lj89ayo5df4suj6/Error.mp4?dl=0